# How can I get depth data from Kinect?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I'm quite new to ROS. I'm using the Ubuntu 12.04 and openni driver.

What I've been trying to do is to use Kinect to detect whether a door is open or closed. My idea is to write a node to subscribe to `camera/depth/image`, and and can retrieve a distance at the center point in the image.

But when I use `rostopic echo camera/depth/image` I just get a lot of numbers like `0, 0, 65, 128, 36, 56, 77, 102, 140, 65`.
So does anyone know what should I do with these numbers, or are there other ways to get depth data?

---

Firstly, thank Martin Günther's answer, it really help me a lot. And I already solve the problem by using OpenCV. Here is part of my code, it's very easy. If some beginners cannot understand that hackish solution, maybe you should try this one:

```
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include ..........

namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
    {
      cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::TYPE_16UC1);//now cv_ptr is the matrix, do not forget "TYPE_" before "16UC1"
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
      return;
    }

    int depth = cv_ptr->image.at<short int>(cv::Point(240,320));//you can change 240,320 to your interested pixel
    ROS_INFO("Depth: %d", depth);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{.........}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160611/how-can-i-get-depth-data-from-kinect?/) by [shinnqy](https://answers.ros.org/users/15566/shinnqy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-05-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-10-20**:
Hello, thanks for updating your solution here. It is quite easy to understand. But I have a question. Is there any quick solution to get the minimum depth of pixels. I know doing a for loop will give me the minimum depth. But is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you're on the right track, subscribing to the depth image is a good way to figure out the distance. The numbers you mention are a one-dimensional integer array (`data`); what you now have to do is convert that into a two-dimensional float array that is indexed by pixels and where each float specifies the depth in meters. The `encoding` field tells you which encoding to use.

Some pointers:

- OpenCV seems to be a good option (see [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/46746/need-help-with-accessing-the-kinect-depth-image-using-opencv/)) to do what you want
- There is a horribly hackish solution [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/90696/get-depth-from-kinect-sensor-in-gazebo-simulator/)
- [REP 118](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0118.html) specifies the representation of depth images in ROS
- the comments in [sensor_msgs/Image](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/indigo-devel/sensor_msgs/msg/Image.msg) are very helpful to understand what's going on

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shinnqy](https://answers.ros.org/users/15566/shinnqy/) on 2014-05-22**:
Thank you very much. I already solved the problem. The hackish solution you mentioned works, but it's difficult for a beginner like me to understand. So I tried OpenCV as you answered and I will update it under my question for other beginners.

**Comment by [Jluis619](https://answers.ros.org/users/26927/jluis619/) on 2016-06-06**:
Hello, could you give me the full code? I'm new to this. and I would like to work with images in depth. Thank you... :)

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-10-07**:
Hi, I was using the rostopic  "/camera/depth/points" .... I thought I was in the right track for getting depth data to measure the distance...
Can you please suggest me if it works in a right way or not?

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-05-19**:
thx for sharing your answer, can u plz provide the full file, I am getting numbers for depth data and I don't know how to read it.
plz guide me more

**Comment by [waschbaer](https://answers.ros.org/users/30263/waschbaer/) on 2017-06-12**:
But actually you should normalized it right?